# SQL Join Issue PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a SQL join to return records from one table for users who don't have a corresponding entry in a second table against the record in the first table. The query I'm trying is below, which I think should return what I want, but it's giving a syntax error:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `suppliers` LEFT OUTER JOIN `matches` ON suppliers.supplierid = matches.supplier_id WHERE '" . $_SESSION['userEmail'] . "' NOT IN matches.user";
```

Any ideas or suggestions? What I'm trying to achieve from the above is to only show results for which the logged in user hasn't marked the supplier record as viewed.

TIA

Comment: Your where clause is not correct. That is I can see.

Comment: Are any of your past questions not solved? If they are, you should mark them off as solved. You haven't commented under any of the answers given neither.

Comment: That ^ was a question and it deserves an answer, just like your question. So, *what say ye?*

Comment: @FahadAnjum and you are one of the very few wise ones ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `suppliers` LEFT OUTER JOIN `matches` ON suppliers.supplierid = matches.supplier_id WHERE matches.user NOT IN '" . $_SESSION['userEmail'] . "'";
```

not in clause not added properly.

Answer (score 0):

correct your where clause :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `suppliers` LEFT OUTER JOIN `matches` ON suppliers.supplierid = matches.supplier_id WHERE matches.user NOT IN ('" . $_SESSION['userEmail'] . "')  ";
```

OR if it is single value then you can use `!=` instead of `not in`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `suppliers` LEFT OUTER JOIN `matches` ON suppliers.supplierid = matches.supplier_id WHERE matches.user != '" . $_SESSION['userEmail'] . "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should swap your WHERE Conditions and trim with brackets ().

```
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM `suppliers` LEFT OUTER JOIN `matches` 
    ON suppliers.supplierid = matches.supplier_id 
    WHERE matches.user NOT IN ('" . $_SESSION['userEmail'] . "')
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is just not correct.  You can use `LEFT JOIN`, but the query should look like:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM suppliers s LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     matches m
     ON m.supplierid = s.supplier_id AND
        m.user IN ('" . $_SESSION['userEmail'] . "')
WHERE m.supplierid IS NULL;
```

Note:  This row may be causing a syntax error or unexpected results:

```
        m.user IN ('" . $_SESSION['userEmail'] . "')
```

You will need to look at the syntax after variable substitution to figure that one out.  This answer addresses the logic of the query, so it will do what you actually want when the syntax is fixed.